# Conditional html in email for Outlook works, but not with Office 365

Tags: html, email, outlook

In html email, the following conditional html works fine to exclude certain content from all versions of Outlook  except, for some reason, Office 365:

```
  <!--[if !mso]><!-->
  Thank goodness you are not using Microsoft for your email!
  <!--<![endif]-->
```

Office 365 still displays that snippet.

What conditional html will let us exclude content when viewed on ANY Microsoft email client (eg, Outlook or Office 265)?

(Note based on another SO thread dealing with Outlook, but not Office265, I also tried `<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->` instead of `<!--[if !mso]><!-->` with the same results... Office 365 shows the content that should be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

This would target Office 2013 aka Office 365 only but I believe conditional comments may no longer be supported..

```
<!--[if mso 15]>

<![endif]-->
```

so the opposite would be to target everything except:

```
<!--[if !mso 15]><!-->

<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: !mso doesn't work, which is in theory all versions, for Office 365.